# Scala custom collection fails to pick correct map function in for-comprehension

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections, for-comprehension

I've implemented a custom collection class which is basically a `Map` with implicit integer keys and values that are subclasses of `AnyRef`. It uses the `Int` keys as index for underlying array structure. Here is the class declaration signature (class instantiation is done in companion object, hence private constructor):

```
class ArrayMap[T >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag] private (private var data: Array[T]) { self =>
   ...
}
```

Now I want to add required methods for for-comprehension. I've defined two different map functions. One that returns a `List` and the other one returns the same data type (`ArrayMap`).

```
def map[X](f: (Int, T) => X): List[X] = { ... }
def map[X >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag](f: (Int, T) => X): ArrayMap[X] = { ... }
def foreach(f: (Int, T) => Unit): Unit = { ... }
def flatMap[X >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag](f: (Int, T) => Iterable[(Int, X)]): ArrayMap[X] = { ... }
def filter(p: (Int, T) => Boolean): ArrayMap[T] = { ... }
```

No implicit is defined. Above functions work as expected when used separately. The problem is in for-comprehensions. For loop either picks the first `map` which returns `List` or throws a mysterious error. The following example produces error:

```
val map = ArrayMap.empty[Integer]
map(0) = 0
map(1) = 1
map(5) = 2
map(6) = 3
map(10) = 4

val rs: ArrayMap[String] = for (e <- map) yield e._2.toString
```

Above code throws:

```
Error:(293, 41) missing parameter type
        val rs: ArrayMap[String] = for (e <- map) yield e._2.toString
```

What am I missing?

**[UPDATE]**

The full implementation is available as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/majidazimi/0b387738fe472c38c2828a9a77f68566).

Comment: _"No implicit is defined"_, that's wrong. This type signature `[X: ClassTag]` is a [**context bound**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html), which gets translated as `(implicit ev: ClassTag[X])`. That may explain the missing parameter type error - however, I don't know why it didn't worked, it seems fine to me.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I need `[X: ClassTag]` so I can do something like `new ArrayMap(new Array[T](size))` in companion object.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that maybe that implicit parameter is causing the error. However, I don't know why, it still doesn't make sense to me - I'm playing in the relp with a dummy implementation of your class, hope I can find something.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Please see the full implementation in the provided gist.

Comment: Nevermind about the implicit, the problem is a type error, because in your `map` function you expect a function that takes two arguments, but in the for  you treat it like a function of one argument which is a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to a type mismatch, you defined the function to pass to `map` as a function of two arguments *(`Int` & `T`)* to `X`. while in your for comprehension you treat it as a function of one argument *(a tuple `(Int, T)`)* to `X`.

The simplest solution is to redefine your `map` function signature. *e.g.*

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class ArrayMap[T >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag] (val data: Array[T]) {
  // Note the double parenthesis (()).
  def map[X >: Null <: AnyRef: ClassTag](f: ((Int, T)) => X): ArrayMap[X] = ???
  def withFilter(p: ((Int, T)) => Boolean): ArrayMap[T] = ???
}
```

With that definition you can make something like

```
val map: ArrayMap[java.lang.Integer] = new ArrayMap(Array(1, 2, 3))

// Note I use lazy val to avoid the NotImplementedException.
lazy val rs1: ArrayMap[String] = map.map(tuple => tuple._2.toString)

lazy val rs2: ArrayMap[String] = map.map { case (_, v) => v.toString }

lazy val rs3: ArrayMap[String] = for {
  tuple <- map
} yield tuple._2.toString

lazy val rs4: ArrayMap[String] = for {
  (_, v) <- map
} yield v.toString
```

See the [full signature](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.Map[B]) of `map` in Scala **Map** as a reference.